# Name of a file in a POST request in Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, post

Given the html form ...

```
  <form id="mainform" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="img"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
        </div>
    </form>
```

... and the handler ...

```
class Picture(db.Model):
  image = db.BlobProperty()

class Submission(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        picture = Picture()
        image = self.request.get("img")
        picture.image = db.Blob(image)
        picture.put()
        self.redirect('/')
```

... is there any way within the handler to get the filename the user entered for the upload?  In PHP, I can refer to $_FILES['img']['name'], but I do not see what syntax, if any, would work with request.get.  In another question, another author uses a javascript routine in his html page to extract the filename the user chooses every time an OnChange event occurs, and then pass it separately in a hidden field.  Is that necessary?  PHP seems to get the filename for free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I uncovered a solution in [the documentation for the cgi module](http://python.about.com/od/cgiformswithpython/ss/pycgitut1_3.htm):

```
picture.local_filename = self.request.POST[u'img'].filename
```

The request's POST object is a collection of FieldStorage, and FieldStorage objects have a filename attribute.